# Clearing DataGridView control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I used the following code to add data into DataGridView control

```
query = "SELECT * FROM primary_student_table WHERE admityear=" & admityear & " AND batch= " & batch & ""
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(query, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "primary_student_table")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("primary_student_table")
```

I need to display records from another table later in the same control so I need to clear the table. How can I do this in VB.NET?

I am using SQL Server

Comment: So why don't you fill the same DataSet with the other DataTable and use that as DataSource for the DataGridView?

Comment: This piece of code gets executed once or twice so that I want to reset the content prior loading it

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Datasource` to `Nothing` then rebind it to the new table.

Comment: Setting DataSource to another table should suffice - no need to first set it to Nothing.

Comment: Well I have run into trouble not using my method.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? It would be interesting to know which issues you get otherwise.

Comment: It has been some ago since I had these error. I don't remember the exact issue, it might have been with some non-databound tables, but setting it to `Nothing` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert but I think you want this.

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

If someone still need help about clearing datagridview :

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear().

DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
```

I hope it helped.